# Bad Request (400) Error when Submitting Login Form with Previously Created User/Password

Tags: axios, jwt, redux-toolkit

I'm encountering a "400 (Bad Request)" error when trying to submit a login form in my React application. The login form is connected to an Express.js backend with MongoDB as the database. The error occurs specifically when attempting to log in with a previously created user and password.

Here is an overview of the relevant code snippets:

routes/users.js

```
// Post session
router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const { errors, isValid } = validateLoginInput(req.body);

  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then((user) => {
    if (!user) {
      // Bad email, return error.
      errors.email = "This user does not exist";
      return res.status(404).json(errors);
    }

    // BCrypt hashes the incoming password, and then compares the hashed output with the one in the db.
    bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password).then((isMatch) => {
      if (isMatch) {
        // Correct credentials, log user in.
        const payload = { id: user.id, email: user.email };
        jwt.sign(
          payload,
          process.env.SECRET_KEY,
          { expiresIn: 3600 }, // Key now expires in one hour.
          (err, token) => {
            res.json({
              success: true,
              token: `Bearer ${token}`,
            });
          }
        );
      } else {
        errors.password = "Incorrect password";
        return res.status(400).json(errors);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

server.js

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import passport from "passport";
import path from "path";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import userRoutes from "./routes/users.js";
import tripRoutes from "./routes/trips.js";

dotenv.config();
const app = express();
app.use(cors());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("frontend/build"));
  app.get("/", (res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "frontend", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("Connected to MongoDB!"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

// middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
// require("./config/passport")(passport);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// routes
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/trips", tripRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on ${PORT}`));
```

session_api_util.js (axios)

```
import axios from "axios";

const baseURL = "http://localhost:3001";

export const setAuthToken = (token) => {
  if (token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = token;
  } else {
    delete axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"];
  }
};

export const signup = (userData) => {
  return axios.post(`${baseURL}/api/users/register`, userData);
};

export const login = (userData) => {
  return axios.post(`${baseURL}/api/users/login`, userData);
};
```

LoginForm.jsx (component)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { login } from "../../slices/sessionSlice";

const LoginForm = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.session.currentUser);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser) {
      navigate("/profile");
    }
  }, [currentUser, navigate]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = {
      email,
      password,
    };
    dispatch(login(user));
  };
```

sessionSlice.js (redux dispatch action)

```
  try {
    const res = await APIUtil.login(user);
    const { token } = res.data;
    localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
    APIUtil.setAuthToken(token);
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
    dispatch(receiveCurrentUser(decoded));
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch(receiveErrors(err.response.data));
  }
};
```

[image: Screenshot of 400 error]